# CORS Request did not succeed, status code: (null) - React Js

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I am currently building an app using Axios as a mean to call the Springboot API that I made by myself. I have allowed header on my controller within Springboot

```java
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(allowedHeaders = "*", origins = "*")
@RequestMapping("/monitoring")
public class MonitoringController {
 ...
}
```

**Other mapping within that controller works fine for me** but one of the mapping I have within that Controller is a PostMapping which saving an input from my React App to my database. However, currently this is my method to do the POST within my React App

```js
<Button color='primary' onClick={() => {
                            const val = { 
                        
                            }
                            val.barcode = data.barcode
                            val.cardType = ct
                            val.modifiedBy = userData === null ? "" : userData.username
                            val.modifiedDate = curDT
                            val.trackingStatus = '1'
                            val.nameFile = data.title
                            handleSubmit(val)
                        }}>
                            Submit
                        </Button>
```

This is my `handleSubmit` function

```js
const handleSubmit = async (val) => {
        console.log("VALUES : ", val)
        const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/monitoring/update', val)
        setCenteredModal(false)
        console.log("RES : ", res)
    }
```

However, whenever I try to do submit - I received the error such as this

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/monitoring/update. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
```

How should I fix this?

/**edit**: I tried using postman to check if there is a fault within the link itself but it works like it is intended with the same request body.